# Recommend a good guide for MySQL optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization

I just upgraded my RAM on my server from 4 GB to 16 GB and I'm told that I can utilize this memory to a huge advantage with certain MySQL settings if I get then just right.  Do you know of any guides that could walk me through some steps I need to look into?  What are the biggest settings I should research?

**update**

Where can I find a simple explination of MySQL's cache optimization features....

My current configuration:

```
query_cache_limit = 1M
query_cache_size = 16M
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### General (and likely overly broad) recommendations:

- Try and fit your whole dataset in memory if possible.
- Optimize your queries and make the cache as efficient as possible.
- Log slow queries.

#### Resources:

- [mysqltuner.pl](http://mysqltuner.pl) is a script in fairly widespread use written by a former colleague of mine. It should give you some basic performance improvements and sane settings given your hardware setup, but this is only a starting point.
- The [MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com) is a great resource. Be sure to check out their book, [High Performance MySQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101716). Here is an excellent post to get you started: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/05/17/mysql-server-memory-usage/
- MySQLForge has some tips that should generally be followed as solid advice, if sometimes a little outdated. The part where it mentions "hire a DBA" may be extremely relevant as your needs grow.
- [MySQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329387) by Paul DuBois is generally regarded as the MySQL Bible. One of the better technical books I have ever read, actually.

Comment: I'm hoping for a simpler source that the one you mentioned... I don't have perl on my server (at least I don't think)

Comment: I would imagine you do. I can't recall a Linux distro that doesn't include Perl as part of at least a core install. If not, you can certainly install it.

Comment: `Try and fit your whole dataset in memory if possible.`  - What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Webnet for example with InnoDB, a good starting point is to make the innodb_buffer_pool_size larger than the size of your database + 10%.

Answer (score 1):

[High Performance MySQL, Second Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101718) -- I've only read the first edition but it taught me tons. The second edition is almost twice as many pages when I glanced at it.

[MySQL query cache simple explanation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) -- It's only a page and the first paragraph tells you what it does.